# Validation callback never calling function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following form validation:

```
$this->CI->form_validation->set_rules(
    'email', 'lang:email', 'callback_validate_email');
```

In the same controller I have the following function (excuse the debugging here):

```
public function validate_email($string) {
    echo 'test val';
    exit;
    $valid = $this->CI->force_model->validate_email($string);
    if(!$valid) {
        $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('validate_email', 'lang:email');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My issue is, the function is never called via the callback. Could anyone suggest what the issue might be here?

Comment: If it is in the same controller, or a controller at all, why do you use `$this->CI`? You don't need that and leads us to think that the code you're showing doesn't come from a controller.

Comment: @Narf it is a controller and the same controller. $this->CI is used throughout the controller, is this an issue?

Comment: It's not a problem per se, but it is redundant and helps you with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone else having this problem, and strangely they were also using `$this->CI->...`

Their solution was to extend the Validation library and add your custom validation callback there. More info here: [CodeIgniter Validation in Library does not accept callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029717/codeigniter-validation-in-library-does-not-accept-callback?rq=1)

Does it work if you set the form validation rules using `$this->form_validation->...` instead? E.g.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'email', 'lang:email', 'callback_validate_email');
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I get the error: "Call to a member function set_rules() on a non-object " using that method however.